# Nasm, C++, passing class object

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, nasm, x86-64

I have some class in my cpp file.

```
class F{
private:
  int id;
  float o;
  float p;
  float s; 
  static int next; 
public:
  F(double o,  double s = 0.23, double p = 0.0):
  id(next++), o(o), 
  p(p), s(s){}
};

int F::next = 0;

extern "C" float pod(F f); 

int main(){
  F bur(1000,  0.23, 100);
  pod(bur);
  return 0;
}
```

and I'm trying to pass class object `bur`to function `pod` which is defined in my asm file. However I have big problem getting values from this class object.

In asm program I have `0.23` in `XMM1`, `100` in `XMM2` but I can't find where `1000` is stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you are seeing `100` in xmm2, I suspect that that is entirely conincidence. The easiest way to see how your struct is being passed is to compile the C++ code.

With cruft removed, my compiler does this:

```
main:
.LFB3:
        .cfi_startproc
        subq    $8, %rsp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        movl    _ZN1F4nextE(%rip), %edi    # load F::next into edi/rdi
        movq    .LC3(%rip), %xmm0          # load { 0.23, 100 } into xmm0
        leal    1(%rdi), %eax              # store rdi + 1 into eax
        movl    %eax, _ZN1F4nextE(%rip)    # store eax back into F::next
        movabsq $4934256341737799680, %rax # load { 1000.0, 0 } into rax
        orq     %rax, %rdi                 # or rax into pre-increment F::next in rdi
        call    pod
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        addq    $8, %rsp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
        ret
.LC3:
        .quad   4497835022170456064
```

The constant `4497835022170456064` is `3E6B851F42C80000` in hex, and if you look at the most significant four bytes (`3E6B851F`), this is `0.23` when interpreted as a single precision `float`, and the least significant four bytes (`42C80000`) are `100.0`.

Similarly the most significant four bytes of the constant `4934256341737799680` (hex `447A000000000000`) are `1000.0`.

So, `bur.id` and `bur.o` are passed in `rdi` and `bur.p` and `bur.s` are passed in `xmm0`.

The reason for this is documented in the [x86-64 abi reference](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation.html). In extreme summary, because the first fwo fields are small enough, of mixed type and one of them is integer, they are passed in a general purpose register (`rdi` being the first general purpose parameter register), because the next two fields are both `float`, they are passed in an SSE register.

Comment: Your code was compiled with optimisations (no extraneous loads and stores). I suspect that the OP didn't use optimizations and _XMM2_ was used temporarily before the `call pod` . He probably thought it was part of the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You want to have a look at calling-convention compilation from Agner's [here](http://agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf). Depending on compiler, operating system and whether you are in 32 o 64 bits, different things may happen. (see Table 5 chapter 7).

For 64bits linux for instance, since you object contains different values (see table 6), the `R` case seems to apply:

> Entire object is transferred in integer registers and/or XMM registers if the size is no bigger than 128 bits, otherwise on the stack. Each 64-bit part of the object is transferred in an XMM register if it contains only float or double, or in an integer register if it contains integer types or mixed integer and float. Two consecutive floats can be packed into the lower half of one XMM register.

In your case, the class fits in 128 bits. The experiment from @CharlesBailey illustrates this behavior. According to the convention

> ... or in an integer register if it contains integer types or mixed integer and float. Two consecutive floats can be packed into the lower half of one XMM register. Examples: int and float: RDI.

first int register `rdi` should hold `id` and `o` where `xmm0` should hold `p` and `s`.

Seeing `100` within xmm2 might be a side effect of initialization as this is passed as a double to the struct constructor.